# how to get an elisp function to press TAB?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to activate the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key from within an elisp function.

here is my function:

```
(defun aline ()
    "We insert a pair of dollar signs and position
    point in between them."
    (interactive)
        (progn
            (insert "\\begin{align*}\n\\ \n  \\end{align*}")
            (kbd "TAB")
            (backward-char 16)
        )
)
```

Its desired behaviour is to print out:

```
\begin{align*}
\ <cursor>
\end{align*}
```

Unfortunately it indents the `\end{align*}`

```
\begin{align*}
\ 
  \end{align*}
```

This is fixed in AUCTEX by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
How can I get my function to press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key?

I realise I could fix it by removing spaces after "\n"

```
(insert "\\begin{align*}\n\\ \n\\end{align*}")
```

but I want to learn e-lisp and I'm curious of how to fix this with an automated <kbd>TAB</kbd> press

I have tried the following commands:

> `(kbd "TAB")`
>
> `(insert "?\^I")`
>
> `(tab-char)`

Comment: You can find what function is bound to a key by typing <kbd>F1 k</kbd> and then the key you're interested in. Calling a function by the key it's bound to is possible (not in the way you tried) but it isn't a way to write reliable code.

Comment: Beginners frequently look for ways to have Emacs press certain keys because they have not yet learned how to determine what function is attached to a particular key using features such as `M-x describe-key` or `C-h k`, and then how to include that particular function  (with the appropriate arguments) in the new function to achieve the desired result.  You can read about function arguments by typing `M-x describe-function` or `C-h f`.  Certain functions also behave differently depending upon whether they are called interactively, or non-interactively.  You may want to use `call-interactively`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 6 years later, but, are you familiar with [yasnippets](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet)?

It solves the problem :)

If you install yasnippets-snippets there is already the align snippet (https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/master/snippets/latex-mode/align)

You can create a new one using the shortcut you think is better

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: align
# key: ali
# --
\begin{align}
\label{$0}
$1
\end{align}
```

In this case is "ali". I have trillions of snippets of my own, they enhance my productivity a lot

Comment: Better late than never! I was not familiar with yasnippets. Thanks and Happy New Year @Laura

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
(execute-kbd-macro [?\t])
```

to activate the tab key.

Comment: That would do different things in different modes - it's also rather obscure even if you only want to execute it in a single mode. It's better IMO to find out the function that the key is bound to and call that.

Comment: I agree to be careful when to use this call.  OTOH this call is an option.  It could be useful for writing tests, I guess.